# pruning Neural Network

Tags: r, logistic, neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction

Since a feedforward NN with a logistic function as activation function is not linear, does it make sense to reduce variables first with principal components or discriminant analysis?

Because shouldn't be done this before training the NN as with logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed having a smaller set of features makes any predictive model (neural network in case) more efficient and robust towards overfitting and noise. However, you should be careful when you are doing this.

e.g if you are sub setting your data in the training and test set; you should do the PCA separately on the training and test; the same for logistic regression; if you are finding features through cross validation, your neural network should be trained and test exactly on the same sets of your cross validation.

however, "pruning" refers to cutting unnecessary connection within the neural network; and it is not exactly what you have described.